# AdaptiveCards throws an exception during .NET parsing

Tags: c#, json, .net, adaptive-cards

I currently encountered the following problem parsing an adaptive card.

This is the card:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "{{DATE(${$root.AdditionalData['DUE-DATE']},COMPACT)}}",
            "wrap": true
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the card-content:

```
{
    "AdditionalData": {
      "DUE-DATE": "2021-09-10T16:29:59Z"
    }
}
```

Code:
c# on .NET Framework 4.7.2 where `layout` is a string with the above card and `content` is a string with the above card-content:

```
 AdaptiveCardTemplate template = new AdaptiveCardTemplate(layout);
 string cardJson = template.Expand(content);

 AdaptiveCardParseResult card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(cardJson);
```

And it crashes with:

```
AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveSerializationException: 'Error reading string. Unexpected token: Undefined. Path 'text', line 1, position 137.'
JsonReaderException: Error reading string. Unexpected token: Undefined. Path 'text', line 1, position 137.
```

The generated JSON on cardJson looks wrong to me at the text property:

```
{"type":"AdaptiveCard","$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json","version":"1.4","body":[{"type":"TextBlock","text":,"wrap":true}]}
```

I'm using the adaptive cards nuget packages:

- AdaptiveCards 2.7.2
- AdaptiveCards.Templating 1.2.

Did I encounter a parsing bug? The value for the text property should be 10.9.2021.

In the designer on adaptivecards.io everything works fine for some reason.  Does anyone have a fix/workaround?

Comment: The *generated JSON on cardJson* is definitely malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error that `"text": ,` is missing the property value.  So the problem is not in parsing, it is in JSON generation.  What are you expecting to get for the value of `"text"` in `cardJson`?  Is it `"{{DATE(2021-09-10T16:29:59Z, COMPACT)}}"`?

Comment: @dbc The value should be 10.9.2021. Normally adaptive cards render it in the given context. It works with the adaptivecards designer online (adaptivecards.io), but not with .Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the literal `"text":"10.9.2021"` to appear in your `cardJson`, use `"${formatDateTime(AdditionalData['DUE-DATE'], 'd.M.yyyy')}"` to generate the required value for your TextBlock:

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.4",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "${formatDateTime(AdditionalData['DUE-DATE'], 'd.M.yyyy')}",
      "wrap": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This causes all date formatting to be performed by the `AdaptiveCardTemplate` and results in:

```json
{
   "type":"AdaptiveCard",
   "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
   "version":"1.4",
   "body":[
      {
         "type":"TextBlock",
         "text":"10.9.2021",
         "wrap":true
      }
   ]
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v86EfB).

If you would prefer `"{{DATE(2021-09-10T16:29:59Z, COMPACT)}}"` in your `cardJson` which [delegates date formatting to the `TextBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features#datetime-formatting-and-localization), use:

```json
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.4",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": "{{DATE(${AdditionalData['DUE-DATE']}, COMPACT)}}",
      "wrap": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Which results in

```json
      "text": "{{DATE(2021-09-10T16:29:59Z, COMPACT)}}",
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ylp1AV).

Notes:

1. According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/language#template-payload):

   > - Use *Dot-notation* to access sub-objects of an object hierarchy. E.g., `${myParent.myChild}`
   > - Use *Indexer syntax* to retrieve properties by key or items in an array. E.g., `${myArray[0]}`

   But, when accessing an object property with a hyphen (or some other [reserved operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-expressions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=arithmetic)) in its name, it is apparently necessary to use the Indexer syntax `['DUE-DATE']` instead of Dot‑notation to retrieve its value, passing the property name inside a single-quoted string as the indexer.
2. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/language#binding-scopes)

   > There are a few reserved keywords to access various binding scopes. ...
   >
   > ```
   > "$root": "The root data object. Useful when iterating to escape to parent object",
   > ```

   Thus you do not need to use `$root` when accessing properties of the currently scoped object (which is, by default, the root) when using Dot-notation.  If for whatever reason you need or want to address the root object directly, you may use `$root` like so:

   ```json
   "text": "${formatDateTime($root.AdditionalData['DUE-DATE'], 'd.M.yyyy')}",
   ```

   Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fh2Wcu).

   However, it seems that using `$root` in combination with `{{DATE()}}` causes malformed JSON to be generated.  I.e.

   ```json
     "text": "{{DATE(${$root.AdditionalData['DUE-DATE']}, COMPACT)}}",
   ```

   results in `"text":,` as indicated in your question.

   Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4XddO).

   This looks to be a bug in the framework.  Possibly the parser is choking on the sequence of tokens `${$`, as your issue somewhat resembles [Issue  #6026: [Authoring][.NET][Templating] Inconsistency in accessing $root inside a $when property in adaptive card templating](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/6026) which reports a failure to parse `"$when": "${$root.UserName != null}"` correctly.

   You can avoid the problem either by omitting `$root` entirely, or by wrapping `$root.AdditionalData['DUE-DATE']` in an additional `formatDateTime()` like so:

   ```json
      "text": "{{DATE(${formatDateTime($root.AdditionalData['DUE-DATE'])}, COMPACT)}}",
   ```

   Resulting in

   ```json
      "text": "{{DATE(2021-09-10T16:29:59.000Z, COMPACT)}}",
   ```

   Demo fiddle #5 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eOtwG0).
3. From the documentation page [Adaptive Card Templating SDKs: Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/sdk#troubleshooting):

   > Q. Why date/time in RFC 3389 format e.g "2017-02-14T06:08:00Z" when used with template doesn't works with TIME/DATE functions?
   > A. .NET sdk nuget version 1.0.0-rc.0 exhibits this behavior. this behavior is corrected in the subsequent releases... Please use formatDateTime() function to format the date/time string to RFC 3389 as seen in [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/db99ee07dadf317fe45e114a508e3de6e4325d0f/samples/Templates/Elements/Template.Functions.DateFunctions.json#L28), or you can bypass TIME/DATE functions, and just use formatDateTime(). For more information on formatDateTime(), please go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#date-and-time-functions).

   While this recommendation to use [`formatDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#formatDateTime) was to fix a problem in 1.0.0-rc.0, the trick also resolves the issue mentioned in note #2 above.